# Too many objects in NSString? %@.%@.%@ produces formatting error

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
   NSLog(@"here is date string %@", dateString);
   NSLog(@"here is file name %@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.%@.%@.%d.MOV", self.latitude, self.longitude, dateString, rand_int ]);
```

results in

```
2015-08-28 13:57:55.378 video[709:261408] here is date string 2015-08-28
2015-08-28 13:57:55.379 video[709:261408] here is file name 40.747062.-73.915204.@.363582320.MOV
```

Seems that the 3 `%@'s` in a row should be `lat, lon, and dateString`, but instead the last `.%@.` seems to turn into plain old `@` in the print out. What am I missing?

Comment: @JohnCaswell because I was testing my NSString constructor as it's also being used elsewhere in a non-logging capacity.

Comment: I've confirmed this problem. Weird. Dunno quite what's going on yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a gremlin (control character) in your format string between the third % and @. You can fix it by putting the insertion point just after the @ and backspacing twice, then retyping the @.

If you open the file in TextMate before making the change I describe, you'll see the extra character:

[image: Control character]

(The compiler for OS X shows a warning for this gremlin, but it's not exactly helpful.)

Comment: thanks for testing the code. Can you elaborate or tell me where I should read more on this? I'm trying to google but not immediately seeing what you mean.

Comment: Okay. Is that better?

Comment: @StevenFisher Got it thanks a lot. I had no idea this was, like, a thing.

Comment: I've run into problems with unicode characters in the past (usually smart quotes around strings, like `foo = @“thing”`), but I had no idea Xcode would just not show that there was an invalid character there quite like this. Wild. Thanks for teaching me something. :)

Comment: Some ASCII characters are not printable. Copy/pasting into another editor such as BBEdit will indicate the character. There is even an editor option in BBEdit "Show Invisibles".

Comment: The surprise to me is that Xcode doesn't have this option. BBEdit (for sure) and TextWrangler (I think) have a menu command called Zap Gremlins specifically for removing these.

Comment: Here is another inviso character that bites me all the time.

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2012/12/23/xcode-sometimes-a-return-is-not-a-return-emacs-brain-damage/

Answer (score 4):

I copied and pasted your code - this is what I see in the debugger:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.%@.%<U+0013>@.%d.MOV"]
```

So you obviously have some no-printing chars in your format string.